# Knowing EOF when using node.js and lazy

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, lazy-evaluation, eof

I have a routine written in CoffeeScript, running in node.js that reads lines from a Jade-file. It looks like this:

```
each_line = (file, callback) ->
  last_line = null

  lazy = Lazy(fs.createReadStream(file)).lines.map(String).filter (line) -> 
    not (
      # Filter the not interesting rows in the top of the file
      /^html$/i.test(line) or 
      /^\s+body$/i.test(line) or 
      /^\s+\/\/\s+Generator.*$/i.test(line)
      )

  lazy.forEach (line) ->
    # We only emit those lines that are whole lines, multilines will become joined
    if /^\t/g.test(line)
      last_line += line.replace(/\t/g, '').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ")
    else
      callback(last_line) if last_line
      last_line = line.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ")
```

Since all this runs async, I need to know EOF so that I can perform operations after the whole iteration is done. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will preface this by saying that I haven't used Lazy myself, but I just looked at the docs.

I was somewhat expecting Lazy to emit an 'end' event, but I can't tell if it does, either way you can bind a callback directly to the end event on the read stream.

```
each_line = (file, callback, eof_callback) ->
  last_line = null

  stream = fs.createReadStream file

  stream.on 'end', eof_callback

  lazy = Lazy(stream).lines.map(String).filter (line) -> 
    not (
      # Filter the not interesting rows in the top of the file
      /^html$/i.test(line) or 
      /^\s+body$/i.test(line) or 
      /^\s+\/\/\s+Generator.*$/i.test(line)
      )

  lazy.forEach (line) ->
    # We only emit those lines that are whole lines, multilines will become joined
    if /^\t/g.test(line)
      last_line += line.replace(/\t/g, '').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ")
    else
      callback(last_line) if last_line
      last_line = line.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ")
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just trying to answer my own question when I found your answer. Do you mean that map automatically emit full text lines? I must check this out.

Comment: No, I must use .lines so that each line in the incoming textfile is returned from .map. Otherwise the whole textfile end up in map.

Comment: Oh, hahah, yeah I was being dumb. You could still do your own thing to process lines, but using .lines IS probably easiest in your case. I'm going to edit my response.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Lazy will emit an 'end' event on the original Lazy object that was created:

```
Lazy = require('lazy')
fs = require('fs')

readLines = (filename, next) ->
  lazy = new Lazy(fs.createReadStream(filename))
  lazy.on 'end', ->
    if next then next null
  lazy.lines.forEach (line) ->
    console.log 'Read line:', line.toString()

readLines process.argv[1], ->
  console.log 'All done.'
```